# 1&1 Hosting - Compilation error for different page.. Fault?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hosting

I was just about finished a new website I've created but as I was fixing an error on a page I've called view-items.aspx I got a compilation error saying a variable is not declared but I haven't touched that part of the code and it WAS working. I now can't even bring the homepage up (default.aspx) as it still gives me the compilation error for view-items.aspx !! Out of desperation I deleted view-items.aspx and I'm STILL getting the same error regarding a variable not declared for a page that now does not exist !! I am using 1&1 hosting with Asp.Net and VB. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. Stupidity !! I had accidentally uploaded the file to the APP CODE folder causing all sorts of problems, when I deleted that it works fine. Thank you